# Installing Signal without using Google Play, Still requests update of Google Play

Tags: installation, instant-messenger

I want to install Signal on my Android 4.4.2

I found countless of reports that it appearently works without it, I followed the documentation here https://k7r.eu/testing-signal-without-google-account/.

But still after the installation when I enter my phone number i get a prompt.

"Google Play-Dienste aktualisieren" "Signal wird nur ausgeführt wenn du die Google Play-Dienste aktualisierst."

Which roughly translates to

"update Google Play-Services" "Signal will only be run if you update the Google Play-services"

I tried installation with apks from both theire Website and Apk-Mirror.

Comment: Signal uses GCM for push messaging, however since v3.30.0 it should be able to work without. Have you verified that Signal really does not work? May be the messages just indicate that GCM can be used it it is available.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is caused if Google Play is still active in the background.

Appearently Signal finds the service, tries to use it and finds that it is outdated. I had to deactivate Google Play via

"Einstellungen" > "Allgemein" > "Anwendungen" > "Alle" > "Google Play-Dienste" > "Deaktivieren"

rough translate

"Settings" > "General" > "Applications" > "All" > "Google Play-Services" > "Deactivate"

After that Signal gave me a notification warning me that using it without Google Play will cause increased power consumption and I could proceed with the registration.

Comment: the solution answer 1 proposes does not work. after deactivating "Google Play-Services", still Signal after typing in my phone number and clicking "Next" it shows "Update Google Play services. Signal won't run unless you update pdate Google Play services."
But I dpn't have and I don't want to have a gooogle account.
Does anybody know how to get Signal running on Android without having a google account? Thanks !

Comment: This solution also stopped working for me on Android 5

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it.

First, disable Google Play services:
Disabling Google-Play-Services works as following:
Applications ("Apps" on my virtual device even in German;) - All (alle) - Google Play services / Google Service framework

click force kill & then deactivate.

If the button is greyed out (disabled):
go to system > administrator users > disable everything in that list

Reference: https://www.guidingtech.com/google-play-services-wont-update-issue/ > section "6. Disable Play Services"

reference2: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/6381

Then restart Signal (quit it before completely or restart device), enter phone number and verify it. Accept that without Google Services something allegedely won't work properly. In fact, it works.